# How to create web service from existing web application?

Tags: web-services, servlets, apache-axis

Greeting,I am new to WebService in java.I want to add webService to existing project which is simply build in Mvc2 and got confuse after reading many article ,Some say,using saaj to create service ,other say use any external library like Axis2 to create webservice or some say use annotation and create xml for mapping.

```
   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {
    String Id = request.getParameter("Id").trim();
    String TD = request.getParameter("TD").trim();
    String Amount = request.getParameter("Amount").trim();
    String Bank = request.getParameter("Bank").trim();
    String NBank = request.getParameter("NBank").trim();
    ApplicationStatus app = new ApplicationStatus(Id, TD, Amount, Bank,NBank);
    ApplicationStatusDA operation= new ApplicationStatusDA();
    int result =operation.insert(app);
    if(result==1)
     {
       System.out.Println("Saved");
     }
   }
```

When I try to use Axis2 then it show error

> The service class "controller.ApplicationStatusCTR" does not comply to one or more requirements of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification, and may not deploy or function correctly.
>     The method "doGet" on the service class "controller.ApplicationStatusCTR" uses a data type, "javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
>     The method "doGet" on the service class "controller.ApplicationStatusCTR" uses a data type, "javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
>     The method "doPost" on the service class "controller.ApplicationStatusCTR" uses a data type, "javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
>     The method "doPost" on the service class "controller.ApplicationStatusCTR" uses a data type, "javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
>     The method "service" on the service class "controller.ApplicationStatusCTR" uses a data type, "javax.servlet.ServletRequest", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
>     The method "service" on the service class "controller.ApplicationStatusCTR" uses a data type, "javax.servlet.ServletResponse", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
>     The method "getInitParameterNames" on the service class "controller.ApplicationStatusCTR" uses a data type, "java.util.Enumeration", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
>     The method "getServletConfig" on the service class "controller.ApplicationStatusCTR" uses a data type, "javax.servlet.ServletConfig", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
>     The method "getServletContext" on the service class "controller.ApplicationStatusCTR" uses a data type, "javax.servlet.ServletContext", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
>     The method "init" on the service class "controller.ApplicationStatusCTR" uses a data type, "javax.servlet.ServletConfig", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
>     The method "log" on the service class "controller.ApplicationStatusCTR" uses a data type, "java.lang.Throwable", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
>     The method "service" on the service class "controller.ApplicationStatusCTR" uses a data type, "javax.servlet.ServletRequest", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
>     The method "service" on the service class "controller.ApplicationStatusCTR" uses a data type, "javax.servlet.ServletResponse", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
>     The method "init" on the service class "controller.ApplicationStatusCTR" is overloaded. Overloaded methods are allowed by chapter 5.5.5 of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification, however, some JAX-RPC 1.1 compliant tools may not allow overloaded methods or may generate WSDL with overloaded operations as contrary to rule R2304 of the WS-I Basic Profile.
>     The method "log" on the service class "controller.ApplicationStatusCTR" is overloaded. Overloaded methods are allowed by chapter 5.5.5 of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification, however, some JAX-RPC 1.1 compliant tools may not allow overloaded methods or may generate WSDL with overloaded operations as contrary to rule R2304 of the WS-I Basic Profile.

Now please guide me which method to follow to create web service.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the type of Object is not supported. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JAXRPC2.html (that's just an example, you should actually see the documentation for the version of JAX-RPC that applies to what you're using)